# Реакция Message-Driven Bean (MDB) на сообщения требуемого типа

Tags: java, jms

В `destination` отправляются сообщения двух типов: `TextMessage` и `ObjectMessage`. Согласно бизнес логике, эти сообщения, исходя из их типов, должны обрабатывать два разных `mdb` (двух различных реализаций `MessageListener`).
Вопрос: можно ли используя `jms.Queue` в качестве `destination`, реализовать такое поведение для `mdb`: исходя из типа сообщения его будет считывать соответствующий `mdb` (то есть реагировать на поступление этого сообщения будет соответствующий бин, а не произвольный) или лучше использовать `jms.Topic` в качестве `destination`, а в `mdb`, например реализовать обработку только сообщений соответствующего типа?

Comment: Можно сделать две отдельных очереди, каждая со своим слушателем. Так логика станет чище, понятнее и надёжнее

Comment: @bobzer  Благодарю за совет. Уже так и сделал